# Firefox not showing fonts / Null charachter

Tags: firefox, themes, fonts

[image: Please see the Screen Shot]
Firefox is making me trouble, is it related to my font folder in usr/share ? or maybe my themes ? Anyone had this problem before and can help me to solve it ? Thanks.

Comment: is this an upgrade to 17.04? what's the context? what did you recently do? where you in 17.04 when it worked before? when did it work? in what context did it work?

Comment: @tatsu  I don't know if itś related to the 17.0 version, I deleted some custom installed fonts in my font folders (usr/share and ~/fonts) and   it works again.  But I still don't understand what happened.